How can I scope an object(not a ViewModel) to a compose navigation graph?
I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. It is finally time to ask StackOverflow. Let's say I have a compose navigation graph and I have a Logging object. I want the logging object to be scoped to the compose navigation graph. Usually, you could use something like @ActivityScope or @FragmentScope for an activity or fragment and that would work fine. However, as far as I can tell, this doesn't exist with compose navigation. Because this doesn't exist, it seems like Dagger/Hilt are useless when using compose navigation because everything essentially either becomes a singleton or you have to pass "navigation scoped" objects manually through to the viewmodels and then to whatever other objects need them using @AssistedInject. I understand that it is possible to do this with ViewModels. However, I am talking about ordinary objects. In my mind, I should just be able to write something like this.
@ComposeNavigationScoped("nav_graph_foo")
class Logger(val tag: String) {
    
    fun log(message: String) {
        Log.d(tag, message)
    }
}

I also know that you can use Feature scopes to sort of accomplish this. However, these have an issue where they don't support process death in any way and also seem like complete overkill for something that should be built into the framework. Honestly, this seems like a very frustrating huge miss by Google. What am I missing? Are dependency injection libraries just dead in compose navigation? Am I really the first person to run into this issue?

Are you running into a case where you have multiple Compose Navigation graphs per Activity or Fragment, such that you want a Navigation graph to be narrower than Fragment despite needing a NavHost like NavHostFragment? Could you manage your own scope/lifecycle with a subcomponent, if you're trying to keep a lifecycle different than the Fragment hosting your navigation?

Also note that ViewModels can be managed through Hilt using @HiltViewModel, but other objects can also be marked with @ViewModelScoped.
